# do prior day orders carry over to next day pre market order in Nasdaq?

Tags: limit-order-book, nasdaq

I am looking at Stefan Jansen's machine learning for trading, specifically, rebuilding Nasdaq order book from Nasdaq itch data. In his [jupyter-notebook](https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/main/02_market_and_fundamental_data/01_NASDAQ_TotalView-ITCH_Order_Book/02_rebuild_nasdaq_order_book.ipynb), he says

> Throughout the day, new orders are added, and orders that are executed and canceled are removed from the order book. The proper accounting for messages that reference orders placed on a prior date would require tracking the order book over multiple days, but we are ignoring this aspect here.

He implies that we need to track the order book over multiple days to do proper accounting of messages. Since messages contain order submissions and cancellations, does this imply that prior date orderbook carries over to the next day?

Comment: It is possible to submit GTC  limit orders that will continue into the next days(s), yes. However the great majority of limit orders are "day orders" that will be cancelled automatically at the end of the day. To simplify your job you could decide to only enter orders of the latter kind.

Comment: are GTC limit orders often used? are there any restrictions to GTC orders (e.g. amount, number of shares, etc)?